# Count the number of colors in images

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I am a novice MATLAB programmer. I need to count the number of colors in an image by using RGB and appear in a histogram. The x-axis will be from 0 to 7 as it has 8 colors same as from binary 000 until 111 (total of 8 colors). The y-axis will be the color value in the image. Here are my programming, but it is not complete.

```
count = zeros (1,8);
img = imread ('peppers.png');
[r,c,h] = size(img);

for i=1:5
    for j= 1:c

    a= img(i,j,1);
    b= img(i,j,2);
    d= img(i,j,3);

    if a >128,
        a2 =1;
    else
        a2 =0;

    if b > 128,
        b2 = 1;
    else
        b2 = 0;

    if d > 128,
        d2 = 1;
    else
        d2 = 0;




        index = 4*a2 + 2*b2 + d2 + 1;
        count(index) = count(index)+1;
    end

    end
end
```

Comment: Your `if`-`else` statements are incomplete, they do not have `end`s, but you have 3 `end`s at the end, what are they ending?

Comment: Your code is actually fine.  Just make sure that there are `end` statements for each of your `if-else` blocks.  BTW, why do you only check the first 5 rows?  Why not the entire image, as that is what a histogram should be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is actually fine (save a couple of syntax errors).  You just have to make sure that your `if-else` statements are ending properly (see Daniel's comment in your question above).  For example, you would need to do this for one of them:

```
if a >128,
    a2 =1;
else
    a2 =0;
end %// CHANGE
```

There is an extra `end` statement at the end of your code.  Make sure you remove that and place the `end` statements correctly where the `if-else` statements are located.  Therefore, your code would thus be:

```
count = zeros (1,8);
img = imread ('onion.png');
[r,c,h] = size(img);

for i=1:r
    for j= 1:c

    a= img(i,j,1);
    b= img(i,j,2);
    d= img(i,j,3);

    if a >128,
        a2 =1;
    else
        a2 =0;
    end

    if b > 128,
        b2 = 1;
    else
        b2 = 0;
    end

    if d > 128,
        d2 = 1;
    else
        d2 = 0;
    end

    index = 4*a2 + 2*b2 + d2 + 1;
    count(index) = count(index)+1;

    end
end
```

You seem to only count the first 5 rows.  I've changed this so that you look at all of the rows.

---

However, if I may suggest an alternative approach, you can do this by avoiding loops completely.  You can simply threshold the entire RGB array by 128, which will produce 1s and 0s for each colour plane respectively.  You can then apply a combination of [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html), [`permute`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/permute.html), [`sum`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sum.html) and [`accumarray`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html) to achieve the desired result.  Specifically:

```
t = img > 128;
out = sum(bsxfun(@times, double(t), permute([4 2 1], [3 1 2])), 3);
count = accumarray(out(:) + 1, 1, [8 1]);
```

The above three lines of code are quite compact, yet there is a lot going on.  The first line goes through each element of your RGB image and sets the output of each plane location to either 1 if the value is greater than 128, or 0 otherwise.  Next, let's take a look at this line of code:

```
bsxfun(@times, double(t), permute([4 2 1], [3 1 2]))
```

A bit of a handful, but no problem to explain.  Let's zone into this part first:

```
permute([4 2 1], [3 1 2])
```

`permute` takes a matrix or vector and reorders the elements such that the dimensions change.  As such, we take the vector `[4 2 1]` (which allow us to compute a unique base 10 number for each bit string possible) and take the third dimension and place it into the first dimension of the output.  Next we take the first dimension (the rows) and place them into the second dimension of the output.  Finally, we take the second dimension (the columns) and place it into the third dimension of the output.  The result would be a single 3D column where the first slice contains 4, the next slice contains 2 and the last slice contains 1.

Now, the job of `bsxfun` is to take your binary 3D matrix `t` and do a point by point multiplication with a second 3D matrix where the first plane consists entirely of 4, the next plane consists of 2 and the last plane consists of 1.  We need to cast `t` to double, as `t` is originally a `logical` matrix.  Because `[4 2 1]` is a numeric array, if you want to use the `times` function, the class of both inputs need to be the same.  `bsxfun` essentially will **replicate** the 3D column vector until it matches the same shape as the binary 3D matrix, which is the same size as your colour image.  The result of this will be such that any red components that surpass the threshold are assigned the value of 4 and 0 otherwise, and similarly for green we get 2 and blue 1.

To compute the index like in your code, we simply use `sum` and sum in the third dimension.  This means that for each 3D column in your matrix, we sum all of the components to produce our index number.  Therefore, `out` will be a 2D matrix that denotes what the index is for each location in your image.  The last line of code uses `accumarray` where we examine all of the elements in `out` and accumulate all of their occurrences.  It's important that you transform the matrix into a single column vector, and so we unroll the matrix using `(:)`.  We also add by 1, as the indices that are generated range between 0 to 7.  Because MATLAB indexes arrays starting at 1, this is why we add this value.

The result should be equivalent to the above code using `for` loops.  In fact, I just ran some results and it does match up.

---

Good luck!

Comment: anyway thank you very much for all of your respond. I have finally solve my problem yesterday. Yes, for sure I have to put end at each and every if else statement.

Comment: I have completed a programming that can count up to 8 colors in images by using the RGB method from 000 up to 111. I need to do some modification to it. So far I declare the number if above 128 will equal to 1 & below 128 will be 0. It will count the 8 colours. How to increase the number of colours count if let say I do it partially from 0-64,65-128,129-192,193-255.

Comment: @RabaniAhmadTasman - This requires making a new question.  Please do that before I answer.